# Component is wrapped in provider but still facing [could not find react redux context value please ensure the component is wrapped in a <Provider>]

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I'm trying to implement redux toolkit for session management all the code is according to provided documentation and the component is already wrapped in PROVIDER but still facing that error. I tried every thing available on internet but still facing same issue. I just started learning react native.

AppNavigation.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {createNativeStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/native-stack';

import Signup from '../Screens/Signup';
import NewSignIn from '../Screens/NewSignIn';
import FullfillmentScreen from '../../FullfillmentScreen';
import Combined from '../Screens/Combined';
import Oragnization from '../Screens/Oragnization';
import {useDispatch, useSelector} from 'react-redux/es/exports';
import {onAuthStateChanged} from 'firebase/auth';
import {auth} from '../../firebase/firebase.config';
import {setUser} from '../redux/slices/user';
const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

const AppNavigation = () =\> {
const {user} = useSelector(state =\> state.user);

const dispatch = useDispatch();

onAuthStateChanged(auth, u =\> {
console.log('GOT USER====\>', u);
dispatch(setUser(u)); //setting user in redux store
});
if (user) {
return (
\<NavigationContainer\>
\<Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{headerShown: false}}\>
{/\* \<Stack.Screen name="NewSignIn" component={NewSignIn} /\> */}
\<Stack.Screen name="Organization" component={Oragnization} /\>
\<Stack.Screen name="Combined" component={Combined} /\>
\<Stack.Screen
name="FullfillmentScreen"
component={FullfillmentScreen}
/\>
\</Stack.Navigator\>
\</NavigationContainer\>
);
} else {
return (
\<NavigationContainer\>
\<Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{headerShown: false}}\>
\<Stack.Screen name="NewSignIn" component={NewSignIn} /\>
\<Stack.Screen name="Signup" component={Signup} /\>
{/* \<Stack.Screen name="Organization" component={Oragnization} /\>
\<Stack.Screen name="Combined" component={Combined} /\>
\<Stack.Screen
name="FullfillmentScreen"
component={FullfillmentScreen}
/\> \*/}
\</Stack.Navigator\>
\</NavigationContainer\>
);
}
};

export default AppNavigation;
```

App.tsx

```
/**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 *
 * @format
 */

import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import type {PropsWithChildren} from 'react';
import {
  SafeAreaView,
  ScrollView,
  StatusBar,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  useColorScheme,
  View,
} from 'react-native';

import {NavigationContainer} from '@react-navigation/native';
import {createNativeStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import Signin from './src/Screens/Signin';
import MaigicLink from './src/Screens/MaigicLink';
import Oragnization from './src/Screens/Oragnization';
//import Splash from './src/Screens/Splash';
import SplashScreen from 'react-native-splash-screen';
import {auth} from './firebase/firebase.config';
import NewSignIn from './src/Screens/NewSignIn';
import Signup from './src/Screens/Signup';

import FullfillmentScreen from './FullfillmentScreen';
import Combined from './src/Screens/Combined';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import {store} from './src/redux/store';
import {useSelector} from 'react-redux/es/exports';
import AppNavigation from './src/navigation/AppNavigation';

//const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

const App = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    SplashScreen.hide();
  }, []);

  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <AppNavigation />
    </Provider>

   
  );
};

export default App;
```

**Store.tsx**

```
import {configureStore} from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import user from './slices/user';

export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    user,
  },
});
```

user.tsx(Slice)

```
import {createSlice} from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import type {PayloadAction} from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

// Define a type for the slice state
interface userState {
  user: string;
}

// Define the initial state using that type
const initialState: userState = {
  user: '',
};

export const userSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'counter',
  // `createSlice` will infer the state type from the `initialState` argument
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    setUser: (state, action) => {
      state.user = action.payload;
    },
  },
});

export const {setUser} = userSlice.actions;

export default userSlice.reducer;
```

Tried every possible available on internet.

Comment: I don't see any overt issue with this code. Are you *sure* this is the code causing the issue? Is there any code stacktrace accompanying this error message?

Comment: stop the development server and run it again with clearing the cache

Comment: provide inputs on what to see in the redux dev tools... is the store initialized? does it have user key? do you see the action in the left panel which setsup the user?

Comment: Thanks all for the help I figured it out It was an import issue "import {useDispatch, useSelector} from 'react-redux/es/exports';" The following import was incorrect the correct one is "import {useDispatch, useSelector} from 'react-redux".